# How can I set the underlying representation of categories to be uint8?

Tags: pandas, categorical-data

I have enormous genomics datasets with two categorical columns "Chromosome" and "Strand". I know that neither will have more than 25 values, therefore I'd like to use uint8 for the data underlying the category. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can cast your columns directly to uint8 with numpy

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Strand': [123, 208, 213, 111]})
df['Strand'] = df['Strand'].astype(np.uint8)
df.dtypes
Strand    uint8
dtype: object
```

If you further cast the column as a [Categorical](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Categorical.html) pandas converts the dtype to uint64:

```
df['Strand'] = pd.Categorical(df['Strand']).
[123, 208, 213, 111] Categories (4, uint64): [111, 123, 208, 213]
```

Comment: The correct answer seems to be that pandas uses the correct int size by default!

Comment: See `c.cat.codes` where c is a categorical column :)